# About PostgreSQL Point-in-time recovery

Tags: postgresql

I want to understand a little bit more about Postgres Point-in-time recovery (PITR).

Suppose I have below scenario:

Step 1:

- have a full backup of my postgresql cluster
- select current_timestamp => time point 1

Step 2:

- Do some transactions
- select current_timestamp => time point 2

Step 3:

- Do some transactions
- select current_timestamp => time point 3

Step 4:

- Do some transactions

(I want to do restore now)

after step 4, I want to perform point in time recovery.
Could I first restore to time point 3, then restore to time point 2, and then restore to time point 1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

During point-in-time-recovery, you don't roll back the state of the database from the current state, like you seem to think. Rather, you restore the base backup and then roll *forward* from there using the archived write-ahead logs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I have done some testing with Crunchy PostgreSQL, multiple times restore can be achieved.